# Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference while implementing select2.js, issue with IE v < 11

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-select2

I am working on asp.net application, In page, I have multiple dropdowns which are loading dynamically from a database while changing its parent dropdown like cascading dropdown.

To make the dropdowns searchable I am using [Select2](https://select2.org/) plugin. This plugin is working and supports all the browsers and almost all the versions but when your dropdown options are static.

Since, I am loading ddl dynamically (using server side code) so page gave me described error but only in IE versions < 11, In IE 11 its working fine and in other browsers too.

My Header:

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

On Dropdown change **_SelectedIndexChanged** method:

I am calling javascript function:

> ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Page.GetType, "Script",
>   "SearchableDropdowns();", True)

Js Method:

> function SearchableDropdowns() {
>               $('select').select2();
>           }

Method successfully called from code behind
I am not using any update panel. It's a simple single page asp.net application.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />` in your master page?